# What are the differences between windows service and windows driver?

Tags: winapi, service, driver, sys

What are the differences between windows service and windows driver ?

Don't they both run in kernel mode?

Don't they both run in session0 in win vista&7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Services do not run in Kernel mode. They often do run at a higher privilege level than Administrator (the NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account,) but still in userland. Drivers, especially in Vista and later, more often than not will also run in userland (with the exception of graphics card drivers<sup>[1](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/01/understanding-user-and-kernel-mode.html)</sup>.)

Comment: The Kernel always runs in ring 0 (or session 0.) Services and applications always run in ring 3. Drivers may run in either ring0 or ring3, or both depending on how the driver is designed.

Comment: Ah, I see. All sessions run in usermode.

Comment: Sessions were not introduced in Vista. They've been there a lot longer. What was new was session 0 isolation for services.